# Scala or java data structures for custom "non-strict" sorting

Tags: java, scala, sorting, data-structures

I have a set of items with different equality and sorting semantics. E.g.

```
class Item( 
  val uid: String, // equality
  val score: Int   // sorting
)
```

What I need is to have items in some collection sorted all the time by score.
Bonus is have a quick lookup/membership check by equality (like in hash/tree).

Equal items can have different score, so I can not prefix equality with a score equality (i.e. use a kind of tree/hash map).

Any ideas on combinations of scala or java std collections to achieve this with minimum coding? :)

Comment: I end up with something like: SortedSet for sorted representation + Map(id -> item) for membership/equality. So I can first find out which elements are new/present in a "collection" and then add new elements to map and set. In this way I have sorted view and strict equality. However, it looks not so good :(

Comment: I can't use just Set for membership because there is no means to get entity from the set, I only can have contains() true of false.

Comment: How are you handling the case where you add an item that is already in the set but with a different score?

Comment: Well, its up to some strategy (first wins, average, etc) but I can detect it and process. Thats what I meant by "different equality and sorting semantics". Not all the object data may form quality relationship and some transient data may be used say in UI for representation.

Comment: I suppose that wrapping a `SortedMap[Int, Set[Item]]`is too heavy?

Comment: It doesn't give you a chance to do fast lookups by id ;)

Comment: You can take a look at my answer, that must fit yuor need. But I'm still uncomfortable with the idea of a Setrelying only on partial information of the object.

Answer (score 1):

I would probably use an [SortedSet](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.SortedSet) since they are already sorted. As Woot4Moo pointed out you can create your own Comparable (although I would suggest using Scala's [ordering](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordering)). If you pass that ordering as an argument to the SortedSet, the Set will sort everything out for you - SortedSets are always sorted.

NB: It's the implicit argument you will want so it might look something like this:

```
val ordering = Ordering[...]
val set = SortedSet(1, 2, 3, ... n)(ordering)
```

Note the last parameter given as the ordering

Comment: +1 At least with this solution, you don't need to tweak `equals`.

Comment: The same prob here. SortedSet default impl in scala is a TreeSet, which use ordering for equality... Thats why I'm asking :)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you are asking about. Are you looking for another implementation of the collection or a specific solution to the multiple hashing-problem?

Comment: At the end I would like to have a custom-sorted views on the collection with fast lookup by key (by identity). Just wanted to collect thoughts on this.

Comment: Yeah alright. Well given you've already made the custom Ordering, you would probably be interested in this page: http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/collections-api/collections.html  The performance characteristics for the Set-collection case clearly vote in favour of HashSet. The good thing about Sets is that they're always sorted, so a lot of look-ups that makes the sorting worth-while. As long as the Ordering has been defined the Scala-library really takes care of the rest :-)

Answer (score 0):

A possibility is to build your own `Set`of item, wrapping both a `SortedMap[Int, Set[Item]]` (for ordering) and a `HashSet[Item]` (for access performance:

```
class MyOrderedSet(items: Set[Item], byPrice: collection.SortedMap[Int, Set[Item]]) extends Set[Item] {

  def contains(key: Item) = items contains key

  def iterator = byPrice map {_._2.iterator} reduceOption {_ ++ _} getOrElse Iterator.empty

  def +(elem: Item) =
    new MyOrderedSet(items + elem, byPrice + (elem.score -> (byPrice.getOrElse(elem.score, Set.empty) + elem)))

  def -(elem: Item) =
    new MyOrderedSet(items - elem, byPrice + (elem.score -> (byPrice.getOrElse(elem.score, Set.empty) - elem)))

  // override any other methods for your convenience
}

object MyOrderedSet {
  def empty = new MyOrderedSet(Set.empty, collection.SortedMap.empty)

  // add any other factory method
}
```

Modification of the set is painful because you synchronized 2 collections, but all the features you want are there (at least I hope so)

A quick example:

```
scala> MyOrderedSet.empty + Item("a", 50) + Item("b", 20) + Item("c", 100)
res44: MyOrderedSet = Set(Item(b,20), Item(a,50), Item(c,100))
```

There is also a little drawback, which is actually not related to the proposed structure: You can check if an item is in the set, but you cannot get its value:

```
scala> res44 contains Item("a", 100)
res45: Boolean = true
```

Nothing in the API allows you to get `Item("a", 50)` as a result. If you want to do so, I suggest to `Map[String, Item]`instead of `Set[Item]` for `items` (and of course, to change the code accordingly).

**EDIT:** For the more curious, here is the quicky written version of Item I use:

```
case class Item(id: String, score: Int) {
  override def equals(y: Any) =
    y != null && {
      PartialFunction.cond(y) {
        case Item(`id`, _) => true
      }
    }
}
```